# MYSQL Relational Query Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working with the following DB model

[image]

A client has asked me to make a few changes to their DB, I haven't played with relational databases in a few years, generally work with flat DB's

Could someone help me on my way with giving me an example of how the following query would work.

say if I wanted to

select all films with a title like '%Matrix%' under a certain genreID

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: If you want an easy way to "refamiliarize" yourself how to write complex queries by hand, there are some excellent tutorial courses online, like [SQL Course](http://www.sqlcourse.com/index.html) or [SQL Zoo](http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Main_Page)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use an `inner join` to join the three tables

```
SELECT F.title 
FROM   film F 
       INNER JOIN filmgenres FG 
               ON F.filmid = FG.film_filmid 
       INNER JOIN genres G 
               ON FG.genres_genreid = G.genreid 
WHERE  F.title LIKE '%Matrix%' AND G.genre = "Some Genre"
```

Comment: thanks for the headstart! where would i enter the GenreID number  to search under?

Comment: If you want to specify a certain Genre ID you would add that to the join clause- is that what you want? If so I will edit.

Comment: I would like that if possible.

Comment: Indeed, takes a few mins to be able to mark as answered, big thanks to everyone else who answers also

Answer (score 3):

You need to join the tables first,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.Genre
FROM    Film a
        INNER JOIN FilmGenres b
            ON a.FilmID = b.Film_FilmID
        INNER JOIN Genres c
            ON b.Genre_GenreID
WHERE   a.Title LIKE '%matrix%'
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

but if you want to search for a specific genre, then you might add a condition as well,

```
SELECT  a.*, c.Genre
FROM    Film a
        INNER JOIN FilmGenres b
            ON a.FilmID = b.Film_FilmID
        INNER JOIN Genres c
            ON b.Genre_GenreID
WHERE   a.Title LIKE '%matrix%' AND c.GenreID = 10
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT Film.*
FROM Film f
JOIN FilmGenres fg ON g.Film_FilmID = f.FilmID
WHERE fg.Genres_GenreID = 3
AND Title LIKE '%Matrix%'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a pretty simple join:

```
select
    Film.*
from
    Film
inner join FilmGenres on
    Film.FilmID = FilmGenres.Film_FilmID
where
    Film.Title like "%Matrix%" and
    FilmGenres.Genres_GenreID = ?
```

Comment: We generally don't use old-style joins in answers.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that and will take it into account further on. Bad habits die hard.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Film INNER JOIN FilmGenres ON Film.FilmID = FilmGenres.Film_FilmID
    WHERE FilmGenres.Genres_GenreID = 1 
          AND
          Film.Title like '%Matrix%'
```